# Having issues ammending .csv file data JAVA

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am having an issue with a Java AddressBook where i am attempting to edit and update the values in a row of data stored in a .csv file

I have attemted running through the code and checking for logical errors but cant seem to find what is throwing the try catch exception. This did work at one point and can not figure out what changed for this to stop working

```
    private class ammendActionListener implements ActionListener {

        public ammendActionListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           String filePath = "Personal.csv";
           String editTerm = id.getText();
           String newID = id.getText();
           String newFName = fn.getText();
           String newLName = ln.getText();
           String newAddr = addr.getText(); 
           String newAddr2 = addr2.getText();
           String newPost = post.getText();
           String newCont = cont.getText();

           editRecord(filePath, editTerm, newID, newFName, newLName, newAddr, newAddr2, newPost, newCont);
        }
    }
    private Scanner x; 
    public void editRecord(String filePath, String editTerm, String newID, String newFName, String newLName, String newAddr, String newAddr2, String newPost, String newCont){
        String tempFile = "temp.csv"; 
        File oldFile = new File(filePath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);
        String ID = ""; String first = ""; String last = ""; String addr =""; String addr2=""; String post = ""; String cont = ""; 
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            x = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
            x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

            while(x.hasNext()){
                ID = x.next();
                first = x.next();
                last = x.next();
                addr = x.next();
                addr2 = x.next();
                post = x.next();
                cont = x.next();

                if(ID.equals(editTerm)){
                    pw.println(newID+","+newFName+","+newLName+","+newAddr+","+newAddr2+","+newPost+","+newCont);
                }else{
                    pw.println(ID+","+first+","+last+","+addr+","+addr2+","+post+","+cont);
                }
            }
            x.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(filePath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
        }

    }

}
```

I expected the File to ammend the appropriate data by identifying the ID column rewriting to and renaming the temp.csv file and deleting the original Presonal.csv with the updated row. Executes with no errors

---

### BUILD SUCCESS

Total time: 36.814 s
Finished at: 2019-07-15T11:07:47+01:00

### Final Memory: 13M/47M

***UPDATE ERROR***

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
at com.mycompany.ppaddressbook.ammContact.editRecord(ammContact.java:174)
at
  com.mycompany.ppaddressbook.ammContact$ammendActionListener.actionPerformed(ammContact.java:154)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Don't just throw up a message in the catch block that merely states `ERROR`. That doesn't tell you anything. Use: `e.printStackTrace();` instead then let us know what the actual error really is.

Comment: Thank you for the response i have added the results of the stack trace hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the `File#renameTo()`. According to Javadoc this method relies heavily on platform libraries.

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

Your code works on my environment, but to make it save to use on any Platform, you should use the NIO-Library (New IO). Here is a quick code, that should accomplish what you intend to do. Note that you don't need to flush nor close the Reader/Writer, because the try-with-resources does these things for you.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.editRecord("C:/temp/test.csv", "2", "2", "foobar", "baz");
    }

    public void editRecord(String filePath, String editTerm, String newID, String newFName, String newLName){
        String tempFile = "temp.csv"; 
        Path oldPath = Paths.get(filePath);
        Path newPath = Paths.get(tempFile);
        
        try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(oldPath); BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(newPath)) {
            String read;
            while( (read = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
                String[] line = read.split(",");
                if(line[0].equals(editTerm)) {
                    line[0] = newID;
                    line[1] = newFName;
                    line[2] = newLName;
                }
                
                writer.append(String.join(",", line));
                writer.newLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
        
        try {
            Files.move(newPath, oldPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

## Edit:

Consider using `Files.createTempFile("temp", ".csv");` for your temporary file.

And since there are a lot of possibilities to throw an `IOException`, maybe it is nicer to add `throws` to `editRecord(...)`. You may catch and display the exception on the caller.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped with the issue I was having. This answer has gave me a much better understanding.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solves your problem, please consider hitting the tick or writing your own answer which clarifies the spots I missed. Thereby anyone else may find his answer as fast as possible.